# add class if width > height, jQuery

Tags: jquery, addclass

I'm trying to add class to all my tall images in a gallery. So why isn't it working?

Here's my code:

```
var boxImg = $('.boxImg img');
var boxImgW = boxImg.width();   
var boxImgH = boxImg.height();

boxImg.each(function(){ 
    if (boxImgW < boxImgH) {
        this.addClass('tallImg');
    }
});
```

Comment: what are the ids of your images?

Comment: It seems like you should test the width and height of *each* image (within the loop).

Comment: Also, if the image is not loaded at runtime its dimensions will not be accessible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Order of execution does matter and `.width()` and `.height()` when applied to a set of matched elements, give you the measure for the first element in the collection. Therefore, the approach to take is:

```
var boxImg = $('.boxImg img');
boxImg.each(function() {
    //this refers to the current element you're iterating through.
    var boxImgW = $(this).width();   
    var boxImgH = $(this).height();
    if (boxImgW < boxImgH) {
        //you almost had it right here :-)
        $(this).addClass('tallImg');
    }
});
```

Comment: Thx mate. That really worked neatly.
The "$(this)-miss" I can only blame on being back from my vacation, not touching code for a month or so ;)

Comment: Glad I could help. Enjoy! Don't hesitate to accept the answer :-)

Answer (score -1):

Well i either your question in wrong or your code is because you are asking for if(width>height) than apply css but in your code you are doing opposite(width

Comment: Yes, well, because my code was wrong, which is the reason I asked the question in the first place :)

Comment: But you asked the wrong question you asked about applying css if width > height but in your code even in the correct one you applied css if width < height(opposite) .... Anyway you got your answer thats it... :)